# How to store Methods in a stack or a list in general c#

Tags: c#, list, methods, stack

I have multiple methods in my script that perform transformations on a multidimensional array, such as transpose, shift,swapColumn..etc I want to be able to undo these changes by storing the methods in a stack and taking their inverse. 
what would be a good way to store methods in an list? 
so far I came up with two appraoches
1- store a stack of letters where each letter represents a call to a method, for example t->transopse.
2- build an abstract class called transformation and make all of my methods as subclasses so that my stack can store all different methods

Comment: Do they all have a common signature? Then you can put them in a Listy<Delegate>

Comment: what does it mean for methods to have common signatures? is it return value?

Comment: @RaedTabani the signature is the combination of all parameter types, and the return type; so `int Foo(int x)` and `int Bar(int y)` have the same signature, as does `T Blah<T>(T val)` for `T=int`, but `void Blop(string s)` does not

Comment: no, not all methods have the same signatures. for example swapColumn take two int parameters where transpose takes none, is it a good idea to pass unused value as parameters in order to have same signature?

Answer (score 3):

You can store methods in a `List` using `Func` or `Action`:

```
List<Func<T1, T2, TReturn>>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
TReturn MyFunction(T1 input1, T2 input2)
```

Or:

```
List<Action<T1, T2>>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
void MyFunction(T1 input1, T2 input2)
```

Comment: but what if my functions didn't return a type(void)?

Comment: can I use Action instead?

Comment: Then replace `TReturn` with `void`.

Comment: private Stack<Func<void>> actions = new Stack<Func<void>>(); throws me an error "keyword void cannot be used in this context"

Comment: It's because Stack is readonly I think, use `List` instead. And you can use `Action`, but `Func` is more common with LINQ.

Comment: even List <func<void>> is throwing same error, any other return type aside from void works though

Comment: Okay so just worked out that `Func` Has to have a return value, while `Action` will return void, so use action. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If all methods don't have a common signature you have a couple of options. You can make a generic Stack of `object`s and push them all in there, then when you pop, compare the signature with possible signatures and cast accordingly.

A design-wise better way might be encapsulating the whole method in another structure and making a stack of it there, or using reflection to get it's parameter types and return types and fill it with whatever value you need (which you would also store in the structure, maybe with a `List` of `object`s again and cast back). If you use reflection, you might not even need to store the function object itself and just use strings of class and method names.

Comment: if I wanted to treat methods as object, how do I invoke them? for example object temp = stack.pop() ...

Comment: @RaedTabani you can check them (e.g. using `if (temp typeof yourPossibleFunctionType)` and cast them to the function type, then just call it normally. the catch is, of course, if there are many possible types then this would be inefficient and the second paragraph would be better.

Answer (score 0):

A possible improvement to shad0wk's answer, in case you want to go with your 1st idea, is to maybe have

```
Dictionary<string, List<Func<T1, T2, TReturn>>>
```

that way you can easily pair up your methods and their inverse in a list accessed with a same key.